# Google Cloud Console: Invalid redirect URI

Tags: oauth, google-api

The task I am working now is to set up google authorization to access resources of my organization.

But there is a problem with this task. My organization uses non standard domain for its local network: domain.off. And when I try to set 'http://dev.domain.off:12345/auth/google/callback.html' as a oauth2 callback in the Google Cloud Console (https://cloud.google.com/console) I get 'Invalid redirect URI' error.

I cannot use direct address with correct internet domain because there are many other services in private development domain of my organization I have to use that conflict with different addresses.

I cannot use production enviroment with direct address for the development purposes. Development enviroment has only private addresses, domain.off.

I cannot modify hole development enviroment to change all private dev addresses to public. This is a task of not my compenency.

Is there any solution to my problem?
The only solution I see now is to ask google developers to remove or modify URI validator in oauth callback setting form to accept non standard domains.

Comment: I don't know anything about google cloud. Just the idea. Maybe you could you use a valid url and then use apache with proxy directives like proxypass and proxypassreverse to handle request.

Comment: Is this any help 2 u: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-developers/6j6JNmewCXI

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is to use one of the alternative Oauth workflows.

If all you want is to use the google cloud from your service, go for a service account as explained here: https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2  I have this working at teowaki.com for interacting with google bigquery and it works seamlessly. All you need is to generate a key on the cloud console and place the key on your server.

If you need to identify users, then you can go for the OAuth for installed applications as shown here https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2

In this case, you can choose beetween the users going to a URL in which they will be presented a token they need to paste back onto your application, or being redirected to a URL in localhost. Since I assume you are doing a webapp, you should choose the first option and present the users with a token they need to paste. It's probably not the best UX ever, but being an internal application it is probably doable.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because you gave the only option which does not require a public domain and that is obviously the main problem with this issue. Unfortunately it doesn't really help my development workflow with powder because I wouldn't want a different behaviour in dev and in production but I'm pretty sure you answered the issue of having a lan-only production server.

Comment: Thank you :)  You are right about having different behaviour on dev/production. I thought this would be an intranet application so that's why I provided you with that solution

Comment: And you were right, I just added a note abut having the same problem with powder but the note was bound to the bounty message which has now disappeared

Answer (score 1):

since you cannot use direct address with correct internet domain

you could try something like this

You can create a master subdomain to get all google auth responses and redirect to correct subdomain using the "state" query parameter.

For example create google.mydomain.com and use it as your valid "Redirect URI" and Apache will  redirect this url to each user with redirect (or rewrite) feature.

More info about apache redirects in 
http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Here the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^google\.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=([a-z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.mydomain.com/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you do the consent and redirected to a public domain somewhere you control (using access_type = offline)?

When Google shoots back the auth code, do not use it from the public domain, pass it with http webhook or something to your private domain that is having the constraint, then make the exchange from the private domain. This then allows you to use the domain and callback url differently to anything you want. Note that the redirect_url set with the sdk script has to be also the same as what you set on the console, independently of the server you actually call the exchange and complete the token acquisition.

I am not sure if I'm missing any of your constraints but perhaps this helps.